# Illegal Forward Reference In AsyncTask Class extending BaseActivity

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm facing this error while eclipse project migration to Android studio. I'm getting this error on 3 classes. All these classes are extending **BaseActivity** and calling fields from **BaseActivity**. For example in class **SavingActivity** inside the `onPostExcuteMethod` I'm calling field called `mProgressDlg` from **BaseActivity** and IDE points illegal forward reference to there (well, there is no red line showing under this).

Part of the **BaseActivity** class code

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

public Button mBtnRefresh = null;
public Context mContext = null;
public GridView mGridView = null;
public ImageLoader mImageLoader = null;
public static ProgressDialog mProgressDlg;
public boolean mRefreshing = false;
public int mScreenWidth = 0;
public TextView mTxtNoData = null;
```

**onPostExcute** method in **SavingActivity**:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (SavingActivity.this.mProgressDlg != null) {
            try {
                SavingActivity.this.mProgressDlg.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        SavingActivity.this.mProgressDlg = null;
        if (SavingActivity.this.mMusicInfo != null) {
            SavingActivity.this.mStrMusicFilePath = SavingActivity.this.mContext.getFilesDir() + CookieSpec.PATH_DELIM + SavingActivity.this.mMusicInfo.strMusicFileName;
            SavingActivity.this.refreshPage();
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need anything else to analyse.

**EDIT:** I even commented out the `onPostExecute` method and tried building apk from cli `gradlew lintRelease` but it's pointing out the error `illegal forward reference to the line which I actually commented. Please see attached images.

[image: cli build apk error]

[image: commented onPostExecute method]

**Error Log From Terminal:**

```
> Task :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
E:\Android-Projects-Workspace\name\app\src\main\java\com\name\activities\SavingActivity.java:113: error: illegal forward reference
            if (BaseActivity.mProgressDlg != null) {
             ^
```

Comment: Your Progress Dialog is declared in `BaseActivity` not in `SavingActivity` . its a Static field so it should be accessed as `BaseActivity.mProgressDlg`.  As a side not do not create static stuff i a instance one would work .

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio (or eclipse) tag just because you use it: the Android Studio and Eclipse tags should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it.

Comment: Well, my issue have relation to Android Studio IDE.

Comment: @Zoe This is 100% Android Studio's issue that's why I've put android-studio tag. Please understand the question before demoting it.

Comment: @Joe gradle is the source, not AS. Code in AS isn't the same as it being an AS issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Android Studio points you to the wrong class for that error `illegal forward reference`. Well, actually compiler experience that error in any one of the classes inside the package. So do check on All classes and you'll definitely find that actual class which has `illegal forward reference error`.

Answer (score 1):

To solve "**illegal forward reference**", you have to know that below two lines READING the static fields `mProgressDlg` is not allowed in Java, see [static Fields constrains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.1).

```
SavingActivity.this.mProgressDlg != null
```

and

```
SavingActivity.this.mProgressDlg.dismiss()
```

Solution is to fully qualify `mProgressDlg` with `BaseActivity`, i.e.

```
BaseActivity.mProgressDlg
```

Comment: I wanna mention one weird thing that is I just comment the `onPostExecute` method but still Android Studio pointing me to same line as before it was commented (I even invalidated cache and restarted). Is there a any way to accurately point out errors? Appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: Can you please check the question again, I updated some info.

Comment: I don't know how to do that.

Comment: try to run `gradlew clean` and `gradlew assembleRelease`

Comment: Well, I tried that. Build after clean was success but unable to build debug or release apk.

Comment: Updated the question with log from terminal

Comment: I would suggest your not define the `mProgressDlg` as static but make is be an instance field.

Comment: Well, Nithis Kumar provided the correct suggestion. I checked the all classes inside the package and found that error on one different class' field creation. After correcting that the error was gone. it seems it was a bug in android studio. thanks for your support.